# Default destructor issue, it isn't detected

Tags: c++, class, destructor

I tried to use my own destructor instead of the default destructor but I get the following error anyhow. Does anyone know why I'm getting this?

error:

```
AssignmentRepository.o: In function `ZNSt6vectorI10AssignmentSaIS0_EE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPS0_S2_EERKS0_':
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/bits/vector.tcc:308: undefined reference to `Assignment::~Assignment()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/bits/vector.tcc:308: undefined reference to `Assignment::~Assignment()'
AssignmentRepository.o: In function `ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorI10AssignmentE7destroyEPS1_':
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/ext/new_allocator.h:118: undefined reference to `Assignment::~Assignment()'
AssignmentRepository.o: In function `ZSt8_DestroyI10AssignmentEvPT_':
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/bits/stl_construct.h:94: undefined reference to `Assignment::~Assignment()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Code of the class in .h file:

```
#ifndef ASSIGNMENTREPOSITORY_H_
#define ASSIGNMENTREPOSITORY_H_

#include "Assignment.h"
#include <vector>

class AssignmentRepository{
private:
    vector <Assignment> assignments;
public:
    vector <Assignment> getAll();
    void save(Assignment);
    void editAssignment(Assignment);
    int searchById(int);
    void printAllAssignments();
    int findByName(string name);
    Assignment *getAssignment(int i);

    ~AssignmentRepository();
};

#endif /* ASSIGNMENTREPOSITORY_H_ */
```

.cpp file of the class:

```
int AssignmentRepository::searchById(int a){
for(unsigned i=0; i<assignments.size(); i++){
    if(a == assignments[i].getID()){
        return i;
    }
}
return 0;
}

AssignmentRepository::~AssignmentRepository(){
}
```

Assignment.h class header:

```
class Assignment {
private:
    int id;
    int grade;
    int dLine;
    string descrption;


public:
    Assignment(int gr, int dl, string desc):grade(gr),dLine(dl),descrption(desc){};
    ~Assignment();

    void setGrade(int value)         {grade = value;}
    void setDLine(int value)         {dLine = value;}
    void setDescription(string value)   {descrption = value;}
    void setID(int value)   {id = value;}
    int getID()                 const{return id;}
    int getGrade()              const{return grade;}
    int getDLine()              const{return dLine;}
    string getDescription()     const{return descrption;}

    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const Assignment& assignment)
    {
        out << assignment.grade << " " << assignment.dLine << " " << assignment.descrption <<endl;
        return out;
    }
};

#endif /* ASSIGNMENT_H_ */
```

Comment: The error is saying it can't find the destructor for the Assignment class. So show us the header and source for that class, not just AssignmentRepository.

Comment: Also show us your build line—if you're not compiling Assignment.cpp, or compiling it but not including Assignment.o in the link step, etc., you'll also get this error.

Comment: i incldue Assigment.h in Assignmentrepositorie.h ... so i suppose that is not the reason..

Comment: OK, now that you've shown us Assignment.h: Is there an Assignment.cpp? Or anywhere else that ~Assignment is actually defined? If not, the error is exactly what the linker is saying: You're using ~Assignment and haven't defined it aywhere.

Comment: Oh, damn, I voted to close as dupe the wrong question. Sorry about that :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have declared the `Assignment` destructor, but you have not defined it.

Try replacing this line:

```
~Assignment();
```

with this one:

```
~Assignment() {}
```

Comment: yup did the job, thank you. I can't belive i  didn't notice... but atleast i get familiar with c++ errors :))

Comment: @user1388172: If you'd shown us the entire program in the first place, you would have gotten this answer immediately. (It's worth getting familiar with StackOverflow as well as with C++...)

Comment: Sorry  i`m working for some hours now at the program and i`m  to tired maybe to pay attention as i suppose, i pasted the part were i got the error beliving there was the problem... i`ll pay more attention in the future. +i didnt paste more because i read i have to paste only the code were it is a problem... so the code part won't be to long

Comment: Yes, but in this case, the linker was giving you an error about the Assignment class, so that's what we needed to see—but you only posted the code about the AssignmentRepository class. Anyway, it's not a big deal—all it caused was a 5 minute delay, after all.